# What running routine will have best effect on long distance walking performance?

Tags: running, cardio, endurance, walking

So I want to improve my performance for long distance hikes. In particular, im trying to improve my time for completing 4 day marches, a Dutch event where participants walk 50 km daily for 4 days. I, unfortunately, do not have time to do hikes that long on frequent basis. I do work out, and as part of it i run. I was curious what can i tweak about my running (weight, speed, time, incline, etc.) to make sure i receive maximum possible carry over for long distance walking.